# How to transform Int to String?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to transform Int to String! to use an int in a text field. I transformed Int to String, but not String!.

Here's what I did

```
func checkAnswer() {
    var answerInInt = String(stringInterpolationSegment: getQuestion())
    if answerBox.text == answerInString {
        questionLabel.text = getQuestion().0
        answerBox.text = ""
    } else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for an optional string, how about something like:

```
var myString : String? = String(answerInInt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 let x : Int = 45

var stringValue = "\(x)"

println(stringValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var intValue:Int? = 5
var stringValue:String? = String(intValue!)

println("Int value:\(intValue!), String value:\(stringValue!)") 
//Output:- Int value:5, String value:5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in both the way:

```
var intValue : Int = 111
var stringValue : String?
stringValue = String(intValue)
```

OR

```
stringValue = "\(intValue)"
```